# Link to does not accept a dynamic url in react router dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating a website and in one place I use `<Link to={product.id}>` it does not show anything but when I wrote like this `<p>{product.id}</p>` it shows the id.

Comment: I just figured it out should have added {"/products/" + product.id} instead of only {product.id}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
<Link
   to={`/products/${product.id}`}
   key={product.id}
>
   ...
</Link>
```